# Using different Ruby versions with URU

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have just installed URU in order to manage different ruby installs. I am actually upgrading from Ruby 2.16 to 2.26 in order to upgrade my Rails app from Rails 4 to Rails 5.

I have not yet decided to upgrade to Rails 5 but instead using the new ruby version (2.26) to go on developping my current app.

Though when trying to do a `rake db:migrate` I ended up with a `no such file error` while reverting to ruby 2.16 the `rake db:migrate` went successfully.

I have installed this new version with Ruby installer for Windows, skipping the Devkit as it should be the same a for the 2.16 version.

Any idea where the problem comes from ?

Comment: have you installed bundler? After installing a new ruby version you must always run: `gem install bundler` and `bundle install`

Comment: should that be done inside my application folder ? If I understand well, all gems have to be updated to new ruby version ?

Comment: yes, your new ruby version does not have a single gem at all. They are all installed on your older ruby version. So the first gem you install is bundler and then you let it do the rest ;)

Comment: Great !! Thanks :)